# Walmart Marketplace API JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, walmart-api

Walmart introduced a new version of the Marketplace API schema (v4): https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#theItemObject
and, unlike previous versions, it only provides the JSON format (previous versions had XSD schemas).
I wanted to convert the schema into entities but it turned out the files were not actually classic [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/).
Does anybody know what format it is and if there's any tools for parsing and converting it?

Example of a schema:
https://developer.walmart.com/xsd/marketplace/items/Spec-4.0/MP_ITEM_SPEC_4.0.json

```
{
    "Headers": {
        "key": "headers",
        "name": "Headers",
        "attributes": {
            "requestId": {
                "key": "request_id",
                "name": "Request ID",
                "xmlName": "requestId",
                "requirementLevel": "Recommended",
                "closedList": "N",
                "multiSelect": "N",
                "minDataLength": 1,
                "maxDataLength": 64,
                "isComplex": false,
                "isChild": false,
                "children": [
                    [
                        "Request ID",
                        "requestId"
                    ]
                ],
                "rank": 1000,
                "dataType": "String",
                "definitions": "Partner's ID of the feed, partner's ID to correlate feed and feed response.",
                "dataDefinitions": "Alphanumeric, 64 characters - Partner's ID of the feed, partner's ID to correlate feed and feed response."
            },
            "requestBatchId": {
                "key": "request_batch_id",
                "name": "Request Batch ID",
                "xmlName": "requestBatchId",
                "requirementLevel": "Recommended",
                "closedList": "N",
                "multiSelect": "N",
                "minDataLength": 1,
                "maxDataLength": 64,
                "isComplex": false,
                "isChild": false,
                "children": [
                    [
                        "Request Batch ID",
                        "requestBatchId"
                    ]
                ],
                "rank": 2000,
                "dataType": "String",
                "definitions": "Represents external generated batchId",
                "dataDefinitions": "Alphanumeric, 64 characters - Represents external generated batchId"
            },
            "feedDate": {
                "key": "feed_date",
                "name": "Feed Date",
                "xmlName": "feedDate",
                "requirementLevel": "Recommended",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual schema files on that site contain `"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"`, which indicates the version of JSON Schema in use.  What you pasted was an example payload, which is why it doesn't look like a JSON Schema.

Comment: No, it's definitely not an example payload. https://developer.walmart.com/xsd/marketplace/items/Spec-4.0/MP_ITEM_SPEC_4.0.json - it's a spec describing data schema (example payload can't weight 5 Mb). The only question what format it is.

Comment: You should probably ask the vendor then.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post the schema has had major changes for v4.0

The latest schema is here https://developer.walmart.com/image/asdp/us/mp/item/spec/4.0/MP_ITEM_SPEC_4.0.json